# Nested menu regions in Composite WPF application

Tags: wpf, menu, prism, regions, cal

Is it possible to have nested regions in a Composite WPF application? I want modules to be able to inject new menus, and also be able to inject menu items into an existing menu.

Using the following code the `RegionManager` throws an exception:

> The region manager does not contain the `MainFileMenuRegion` region

```
<Menu cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainMenuRegion">
    <MenuItem cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainFileMenuRegion" Header="_File" />
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I've come up with is to simply use two `Menu`s arranged with a `Grid`. The first one has all my standard menus and allows me to inject into each one individually. The second is empty and allows me to inject new top-level menus.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its 'right' but I do nesting by having a region on the injected view that I then inject the sub view into.

Comment: Interesting, but I need to inject into a region and a subregion which are both in the shell.